# Changing form size from a WM_SIZE message

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I have a form with a minimum height set, because I don't want it resized beyond a certain point when it is in a "minimalistic display" mode.

When a user attempts to maximize the window by Aero Snapping it to the top of the screen, the window gets maximized, but the height of the window is only 240 pixels (the set maximum size).  If I attempt to handle the `WM_SIZE` message when the `wParam` is `SIZE_MAXIMIZED`, any attempt to set the height of the form is bypassed.

Currently I am handling `SC_MAXIMIZE` to detect when the maximize button is pushed, and `WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK` to maximize the window if the user double clicks the title bar.  In both of these situations, I can toggle the extended window mode and set the minimum size such that it will be able to go full screen.

Of course neither of these messages are posted if the window is maximized via `ShowWindow(SW_MAXIMIZE)` or when aero-snapped to the top of the screen.

Is there another message I can handle that might occur just before the system actually does the maximization so I can adjust the window size and display mode before hand?

**Current Code:**

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x0112) { // WM_SYSCOMMAND
        if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0xF030)) { // Maximize event - SC_MAXIMIZE from Winuser.h
            // The window is being maximized
            this.MaximumSize = new Size(9999, 9999);
            ToggleDeviceDisplay(true);
            linkToggleDeviceList.Visible = false;
        }
    } else if (m.Msg == 0x00A3) { // WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK - Double clicking on window title bar, min or max
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal) {
            if (grpDeviceList.Visible == false) {
                this.MaximumSize = new Size(9999, 9999);
                ToggleDeviceDisplay(true);
            }
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            linkToggleDeviceList.Visible = false;
        } else {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            linkToggleDeviceList.Visible = true;
        }
        return;
    } else if (m.Msg == 0x0005) { // WM_SIZE
        if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0x02)) { // SIZE_MAXIMIZED
            // CANT GET WINDOW TO GO TO FULL-SCREEN FROM HERE
            this.MaximumSize = new Size(9999, 9999);

             // THE LINE BELOW DOESN'T WORK, probably because it is already being sized
            this.Height = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle).WorkingArea.Size.Height;
        } else if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0x00)) { // SIZE_RESTORED
            linkToggleDeviceList.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

If the window is already in extended display mode when WM_SIZE maximize is sent, there is no problem because the max window size is set to allow full screen, however, if they attempt to maximize from the minimal mode, I can't get the app to switch to take up the full screen during the message.

I know I could trigger a timer or something to run from the message so it would resize so quickly the user wouldn't notice it wasn't full screen right away, but that is just a terrible hack.

**EDIT:**

To illustrate the two window states, I have uploaded two screenshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkXic.jpg).  The top image shows the extended display, which has no limits on window size, the bottom image shows the minimal display, which has a height restriction set so they can't increase the height of the window as all it would do is show more empty space.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using the actual window message constant values, like `WM_SIZE` instead of the hex values?

Comment: No good reason, at first I was only using 2 messages so I used the values instead of defining them in my app as constants like I should.

Comment: The concept of "the window height must not exceed Y pixels except when the user wants to make it larger, then it may be larger" is silly, from Windows's perspective. Either the window height is limited to Y pixels, or it isn't. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Since your full screen mode is -- again, from Windows's perspective -- completely different from your minimalistic interface, could you not use two different windows?

Comment: I guess that's the problem, it isn't a completely different interface, it is actually the same interface except in the minimal view, only a small portion from the top of the window that shows basic statistics is visible; when in the extended view, the above section is visible, except the height of the window is extended and a large DataGridView below all the stats becomes visible.

Comment: I added screenshots of the two window states to hopefully add clarity.

Comment: @drew010 Thanks for the clarification. My suggestion will be to slightly redesign your interface: you could show/hide the device list by vertically resizing the window, thereby avoiding the entire problem.

Comment: So basically the device list is always visible, except it is out of the bounds of the form when in minimal mode, and then the user could just increase the height to expose the device list?  I originally avoided that method just because it looks strange when the window is resized so only the title of the groupbox is showing or the device list is really small, but if I can't find a workable solution, I think I will go with that method.  Or do you have any tips on managing the resizing a little better using your idea?  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @drew010 No, not entirely: you would handle window resize events to show or hide the device list as needed. To prevent a resize of just a few pixels more than the minimal interface (which would not show the top of the group box if you hide it), you can handle `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` to fix the window to the minimal height until the window is resized to at least minimal height + treshold.

Comment: You can't make this work, there's no snap notification message.  You got into this problem by forcing the user to make your window look pretty.  That's just the wrong approach, keep the user in charge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like you're trying to do a simple thing in an overly complicated way. I would process the [`WM_GETMINMAXINFO` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626.aspx), which is sent to your window whenever its size or position is about to change. Handling this message gives you the opportunity to specify maximal or minimal values for each of these attributes, effectively preventing it from being made smaller or larger than you desire.

I won't post a lot of sample code because your question indicates you already know how to override `WndProc` and handle window messages. The only thing you'll need to do is define the `MINMAXINFO` structure in managed code. Something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct POINT
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MINMAXINFO
{
    public POINT ptReserved;
    public POINT ptMaxSize;
    public POINT ptMaxPosition;
    public POINT ptMinTrackSize;
    public POINT ptMaxTrackSize;
}
```

Use [`Marshal.PtrToStructure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure.aspx) to convert the pointer contained in the `Message.LParam` property to an instance of the `MINMAXINFO` structure defined above. So, inside of your `WndProc` method, you'd do something like:

```
MINMAXINFO mmi = (MINMAXINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(msg.LParam, typeof(MINMAXINFO));
```

---

**Update:**

From the screenshots you've posted, it looks like the two different displays are identical, the only difference is whether the DataGridView at the bottom is shown. The GroupBox at the top is shown, regardless of the form's size.

Thus, it seems to me that the solution is simply to handle the `Form.Resize` event (which should be raised *regardless* of how your form is resized, whether via manually dragging its borders, clicking the caption bar buttons, or with Aero Snap).

Inside of that event handler method, check the current dimensions of your form. If it is sufficiently large, set the `DataGridView` control's `Visible` property to `true`. If it is not of sufficient size, switch to "minimal mode" by setting `DataGridView.Visible = false`.

It's not a very technically complicated solution, but it seems like it should accomplish all of your desired goals. The motivation as I understand it is just to provide a simpler interface when the form is too small to be able to see everything, and expand that interface when the form is larger. If you handle the `Resize` event and check the actual size of the form after that event has fired, you can't be wrong.

An alternative solution is just to enable the `AutoScroll` property and always show both controls. All the user will have to do is scroll up or down to see whatever they want. WinForms takes care of the rest.

Comment: I started experimenting with `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` not long ago because I think it may be the way to go as well.  Now the only issue I have is Windows sends that message when moving the window or attempting to resize it.  If the app is in minimal mode, I want to say the max size is the smaller size, but when they try to aero-snap, I need to trick it into thinking the max size is the size of the display.  Now I am just having trouble figuring out how to know when the message is incoming due to a move/resize vs Aero asking how big the max size is.

Comment: @drew: I'm not sure I understand the motivation. Aero Snap isn't going to make it bigger than the screen anyway.

Comment: See the screenshots [here](http://imgur.com/a/Zap2C).  The problem is, when in the minimal mode, where a height restriction is set on the window, aero snap maximizes the window, but the height is still only ~300 pixels.  I would like to somehow increase the size of the window to the screen size, and enable the extended display at the same time.  Using `SC_MAXIMIZE` and `WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK` work great, but aero snap only posts the WM_SIZE message after it has maximized my window (using the smaller height).  In WM_SIZE, I can't seem to change the height, it just ignores the resize.

Comment: Thanks again, I came pretty close eventually but its clearly become overcomplicated and probably no longer works on Mono so I think Tuesday I'm gonna scrap it and use one of your suggestions.

Comment: @drew010, have you tried my example? It is very simple and works.

Answer (score 2):

Do I understand correctly: you want your window to have minimum allowed size and be able to be maximized? If that is so your code is far too complex and actually not necessary. Just use window's property MinimumSize.

Comment: I do set a minimum size, but when the window is in the minimal display mode, I don't want it to be able to be resized beyond a certain height which is why I set the maximum size limit.  The problem is, if they are in the minimal mode, and maximize the window using Aero Snap, I can't seem to find a way to increase the maximum size prior to the maximization.

Answer (score 1):

So you want your form to have minimum size, maximum size and still be able to maximize it using title bar double click, maximize button and Aero snap? Tricky :-) Here is the solution.

Set you MinimumSize in properties and then write 2 events:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
    {
        MaximumSize = new Size(maxWidth, maxHeight);
    }
}
```

and:

```
private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MaximumSize = new Size(0, 0);
}
```

That will do the trick. At least works on my machine :-)